# CSS @font-face not working in ie

Tags: xhtml, html, css

I have the following CSS that works within Firefox but not IE. Obviously, the fonts are within the directory. Any suggestions?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Futura";
    src: url("../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot"); /* IE */
    src: local("Futura"), url( "../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.ttf" ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

body nav {
    font-family: Futura,  Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Font-face not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327227/font-face-not-working-on-mobile)

Answer (score 11):

I read a lot of tutorials that suggested hacks, so I came up with this solution I think is better... It seems to work fine.

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: MyFont; src: url('myfont.ttf'); 
}
@font-face{ 
    font-family: MyFont_IE; src: url('myfont.eot'); 
}
.my_font{ 
    font-family: MyFont, MyFont_IE, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: This should not be the way you're getting this done. Try a proper syntax: [Fontspring Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax), [Further Hardening of the Bulletproof Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax), [Mo’ Bulletproofer](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/), or [Smiley](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

Comment: The fact that I declared the font for ie in a separate @font-face rule made my day, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10):

If you're still having troubles with this, here's your solution:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

It works far better/faster than any other font-generator and also gives an example for you to use.

Comment: Take care with blacklist. You won't be able to convert some fonts.

Answer (score 4):

For IE > 9 you can use the following solution:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansRegular;
    src: url('OpenSansRegular.ttf'), url('OpenSansRegular.eot');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/

> Now that web fonts are supported in Firefox 3.5 and 3.6, Internet
>   Explorer, Safari, Opera 10.5, and Chrome, web authors face new
>   questions: How do these implementations differ? What CSS techniques
>   will accommodate all? Firefox developer John Daggett recently posted a
>   little roundup about these issues and the workarounds that are being
>   explored. In response to that post, and in response to, particularly,
>   Paul Irish’s work, I came up with the following @font-face CSS syntax.
>   It’s been tested in all of the above named browsers including IE 8, 7,
>   and 6. So far, so good. The following is a test page that declares the
>   free Droid font as a complete font-family with Regular, Italic, Bold,
>   and Bold Italic. View source for details. Alert: Be aware that
>   Readable Web has released it’s first @font-face related software
>   utility for creating natively compressed EOT files quickly and easily.
>   It has it’s own web site and, in addition to the utility itself, the
>   download package contains helpful documentation, a test font, and an
>   EOT test page. It’s called EOTFAST If you’re working with @font-face,
>   it’s a must-have.
>
> Here’s The Mo’ Bulletproofer Code:

```
@font-face{ /* for IE */
    font-family:FishyFont;
    src:url(fishy.eot);
}
@font-face { /* for non-IE */
    font-family:FishyFont;
    src:url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"),url(fishy.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Font API](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-google-font-api-google-font.html). They say it works from IE 6 and up. (I've not tested this.)

> Google’s serving infrastructure takes
>   care of converting the font into a
>   format compatible with any modern
>   browser (including Internet Explorer 6
>   and up), ...

Answer (score 1):

Font Squirrel did not work for me.   I uploaded a font for conversion to multiple font format for IE support.  It performed onversion, which I was able to download.  I then uploaded content to my server per specs.  I was only either able to get Firefox or IE to work but not both. The solution that worked for me was The Mo Bullet Proofer link above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found if the font face declarations are inside a media query IE (both edge and 11) won't load them; they need to be the first thing declared in the stylesheet and not wrapped in a media query

Answer (score 0):

Change as per below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Futura";
    src: url("../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot"); /* IE */
    src: local("Futura"), url( "../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.ttf" ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

body nav {
     font-family: "Futura";
    font-size:1.2em;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try putting an absolute link not relative link to your eot font - somehow old IE just don't know in which folder the css file is
2) make 2 extra @font-face declarations
so it should look like this:

```
@font-face { /* for modern browsers and modern IE */
    font-family: "Futura";
    src: url("../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot"); 
    src: url("../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url( "../fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.ttf" ) format("truetype"); 
}
@font-face{ /* for old IE */
  font-family: "Futura_IE"; 
  src: url(/wp-content/themes/my-theme/fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot);
}

@font-face{ /* for old IE */
  font-family: "Futura_IE2"; 
  src:url(/wp-content/themes/my-theme/fonts/Futura_Medium_BT.eot?#iefix) 
  format("embedded-opentype");
}

.p{ font-family: "Futura", "Futura_IE", "Futura_IE2", Arial, sans-serif;
```

This is an example for wordpress template - absolute link should point from where your start index file is.