# Internet Explorer rejecting my fonts in HTML AND CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I am trying to do

```
@font-face {
font-family: Eurostile;
src: url("fonts/Eurostile.eot"); }
```

But no matter what, Internet Explorer won't use my font.  I did it with a ttf file in Firefox...

How can I get this done in IE?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082835/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Font Squirrel's webkit solved all my problems.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try looking at Paul Irish's fabulous article http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/