# font face wont load on initial site visit

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-face, webfonts

I am working on [speedybarcodes.com](http://speedybarcodes.com) and I'm having a problem with the fonts and font icons not loading on the initial site visit.

It's a really weird problem. If you visit the site, as soon as it loads the first time the fonts aren't shown for the headings and the icon font (bootstrap glyphicons). But if you browse to another page everything works fine.

I have tried what some others have suggest on stack, such as making sure all my font-family callouts have fonts in quotes like: font-family:'specialfont', sans-serif;

I've also put all my @font-face stuff at the top of the css file. Still no luck in fixing it.

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082835/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie) that may help you out. Also there is a good Article by Paul Irish [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) with good information and links to other resources

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on codeigniter; default page is welcome and default function is index. If I click on the home page @face-font loads, but on initally going to my domain

```
<http://www.ginbrookes.tk>
[web](http://www.ginbrookes.tk)
<a href="http://www.ginbrookes.tk"> web</a>
```

the @font-face didn't work even though in theory /welcome/index should have been evoked.

i seem to have fixed it by adding the following to .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```