# Why does my Agency FB font work fine with Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. www.serialquilting.com

Tags: css, font-face

Basically the @font-face is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but not working properly in Internet Explorer. If someone could take a look at it www.serialquilting.com and advise what the issue might be that would be great.

Comment: Did you search other SO questions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082835/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @user2649551 did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is likely because Internet Explorer needs a different font format. There's a great tool for this:

[Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/)

Internet Explorer will work nicely with Embedded OpenType (EOT), and Open Font (OFT)

Comment: As a side note, although you likely already know, your tablet.css file is missing the # for background-color to properly parse.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay in response on this, but while that Font Converter worked splendidly when I tried to install the font in my font folder on my laptop it wouldn't take. If I load it into my FTP will it render properly for the website?