# html2canvas issue with @font-face in Internet explorer

Tags: d3.js, svg, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using d3.js to generate a graph and an image with SVG attributes. I am supposed to convert that page to pdf. Using html2canvas.svg.js, converting that page to image (converting in to base64string), and passing that to jsPdf(jsPdf.js library) object to generate pdf.
Here, I am facing problem that, text below that graph (x axis values) is overlapped by a gray rectangle while converting the page to image, in the Internet explorer.
But in the Chrome it is working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your codes. And which IE version are you referring to?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082835/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie)