# @Font-face not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, font-face

Here's my code it works perfectly fine on desktop and tablet but not on mobile. Is it the code or do some fonts just not work on mobile

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Out';
    src: url('http://location/Outstanding.otf');
}
```

Comment: browser specific issue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add all `src` needed to `@font-face` like this example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

**Source**: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/
Hope it helps,
cheers.

(*If you need to convert the font you gonna need this* *[font-generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) )*

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included (assuming you have them) all the necessary font files:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Out';
  src: url('out.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('out.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('out.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('out.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('out.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('out.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

So *.ttf is missing for Safari/IOS etc.

Comment: It is same as the marked answer, no?