# @fontface custom font not visible on ios

Tags: ios, css, fonts

Hi Im having some trouble viewing the custom font on ios, ive followed the comments here [@Font-face not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327227/font-face-not-working-on-mobile/45897264#45897264) but don't seem to be having any joy

I have uploaded this

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'CeraPro';
      src: url('CeraPro.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('CeraPro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('CeraPro.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('CeraPro.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
           url('CeraPro.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('CeraPro.svg#svgCeraPro') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
 }
```

the website is arcade78.com

Comment: On the site you mentioned the font is used as `body, p { font-family: 'Cera Pro' }` but you're defining it as `font-family: 'CeraPro'`. The names need to match 100% including whitespace.

Comment: thanks Valentin changed that to match but still sadly the same issue on iOS

Comment: @font-face {
      font-family: 'Cera Pro';
      src: url('CeraPro.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('CeraPro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('CeraPro.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('CeraPro.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
           url('CeraPro.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('CeraPro.svg#svgCeraPro') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
 }

Comment: With responsive design mode in Firefox (I know that isn't *really* mobile) the fonts display just fine. Also, your page is very heavy.