# font-face not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, cross-browser, mobile-safari, font-face

I've set up my font faces like stated in the answer to this question: [font-face not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327227/font-face-not-working-on-mobile/45897264#45897264/)

Here is how I have it set up:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'SF Distant Galaxy';
src: url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.eot');
src: url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('./files/SFDistantGalaxy.svg#SFDistantGalaxy') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

and here is it being used:

```
#title {
font-family: 'SFDistantGalaxy';
letter-spacing: 3.3px;
text-align: center;
color: #f8e71c;
font-size: 95px;
}
```

When I open it on my browser, it loads just fine. But when I open it on my phone, it is showing Times New Roman.

Here is the site:
http://starwarsplanets.com/

I would love any feedback for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the css font title to match the font face:

```
#title {
    font-family: 'SF Distant Galaxy';
    color: #f8e71c;
    font-size: 95px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```