# Some font weights won't load on mobile with different @font-face loads

Tags: css, fonts, load, font-face

Some fonts with different weights aren't loading. I'm loading the fonts with font-face in my css file like such:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url("/includes/fonts/globerbold.otf') format('embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: 700;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url("/includes/fonts/globersemibold.otf') format('embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: 600;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url("/includes/fonts/globerregular.otf') format('embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url("/includes/fonts/globerbook.otf') format('embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

So I've figured out that all fonts with the `font-weight: 200` are loading. The other weights: 400, 600 and 700 aren't loading on mobile.

I've tried altering the path to the font in different ways, yet it still won't load.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327311/7821865

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 I've done it how explained in the link you've provided. It still doesn't work. It's still only picking up the font-weight: 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is directly copied from your source code, you’re mixing single and double quotes. That’s probably interfering with the other CSS. Try:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url('/includes/fonts/globerbold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Etc. */
```

You’ll notice I’ve also changed the format from `embedded-opentype`, which was for the old EOT format used by old versions of Internet Explorer to `opentype`.

The browser will (usually helpfully) only load the styles that are actually used, so your other HTML & CSS will be a factor. If only one style is applied, that might be the reason why the others aren’t showing up as being loaded in your developer tools.

If you purchase or already have a package with a web font license for Glober, they should include WOFF and WOFF2 files as well, which will be a better choice than the OpenType font. Most likely, that will also come with a sample CSS file you can use or modify.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glober';
  src: url('/includes/fonts/globerbold.woff2') format('woff2'), 
       url('/includes/fonts/globerbold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Hope that’s helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have the license for the web font, yet it was only provided with OTF fonts. I've generated them into WOFF and WOFF2 fonts on fontsquirrel.com to check if that was the problem. Obviously the WOFF files are loading way faster. But that wasn't fixing the problem either. So to get this straight: I have to add four different font faces for each font-weight, right?

Comment: Yes that’s correct. You’ll have one `@font-face` block for each style of the typeface like in your original example (bold, semibold, regular, book) with the quotes corrected.