# @font-face icon not showing in IE 11, all other browsers supports. Using base64 url

Tags: css, font-face

My @font-face is **not working in IE 11**,in all other browsers anythings shows fine.
There is a console error in IE: "@font-face failed opentype embedding permission check. permission must be installable"

I have search some solutions online, but nothing worked for me. I have sean that this is a common issue in IE, but asking if someone knows something

Here is all the code with font in base64. :

css:

```
.homeicon{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
font-family: iconfont;
margin-top: 3px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "iconfont";
    src: url(data:font/truetype;base64,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) format('truetype');

    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

.homeicon{
  content: "\e902";
}
```

html:

```
<span class="homeicon"></span>
```

Comment: You have to use `otf,ttf,svg,eot,woff` format to support all browsers.

Comment: Similar examples found on the web don't have the `charset=UTF-8` bit, which makes sense, since a font file isn't in a textual format. If that doesn't work, can you post the real code? Otherwise we can't test.

Comment: @Saravana IE11 supports the truetype format just fine.

Comment: @MrLister i have remove the "charset=UTF-8" and still the same results. I found it shold be like this  on web "data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>" and still the same. I'm looking forward for a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Font-face not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327227/font-face-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: _“Here is all the code”_ - this can’t be all the code, because you are not placing any content inside the span here to begin with, you are assigning a font-family only. This is missing the CSS to insert a character via a pseudo element or something. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: This is true, is not the whole code here. But i cant post all the code here, its to much an complex, i wanted to show the example quickly. I know the issue is with font-face. Like i describe its only not working in IE. @04FS thank you for the proper info for Minimal, Complete, and Verifible example, I will take it into account in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the issue. I have changed the font icon to a woff format. Now the font icon is visible on all browsers, **explicit on IE11**.

What i have done is, i formated the font icon .ttf file to a base64 format .woff. I have used this encoder [https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/].

And the sintax looks like this:

```
@font-face{font-family:'yourfontname'; src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,YOUR BASE64 STRING HERE) format(woff);}
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
src: url(data:application/font-woff;base64,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) format('woff');
```