# Icons won't display for mobile html select dropdown?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Basically I am trying to fix a problem with icons not displaying properly for mobile users on the html select element. As you can see below, the icons won't display properly even though I have added the correct font for FA Icons for the select element although I presume it might be a different context and that's why it won't work?

[image: screen]

As you can see below, the icons display properly when the dropdown is not clicked.
[image: screen]

I have this line included in my CSS and everywhere on the website it is working fine except on the mobile.

```
select {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

}
```

Keep in mind i'm using Unicode values as icons and not the i elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Font-face not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327227/font-face-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: hey KeDeN, i think you don't need to set
 `select {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}`
this css because there is a class of font-awesome `.fa .fas-iconName`.  the all css required in font-awesome icon are already there.

Comment: It's simply not supported to have FA icons in options.

Comment: @Tmba I was thinking that as well although I did a workaround with Unicodes but I guess there is no way of fixing it for mobile?

Comment: which version you are using of font-awesome?

Comment: If your are using Font-Awesome 4.7 then use font-family:'FontAwesome'; instead of font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

Comment: or please share your code, for more clarification..

Comment: I'm using the latest version of FA Icons, the problem wouldn't be with the font since I fixed the issue with it before. The unicode wouldn't display unless its Font Awesome 5 Free. What I was thinking is that the mobile version dropdown is out of context? So basically the styles won't affect the mobile dropdown state? If there would be a way to add a font to the default popup for dropdown which is displaying for mobile users I presume that would fix the issue.